Do the moveTo() functions work on pedestrians?
I found the moveTo() functions in the documentation for agents. Since Pedestrian extends Agent, I assumed it would work on them too, but I've been getting this unsupported operation exception:
Unsupported Operation Exception
This is how I'm using it in an event inside my agent type:
this.moveToNearestAgent(targets);
'targets' is an ArrayList of another type of agent.
I have already read this Anylogic help page but it didn't seem to answer my question:
https://anylogic.help/anylogic/agentbased/movement-continuous.html
Am I doing something wrong, or is moveTo just not supported for Pedestrians? If so, is there an alternative for Pedestrians with similar functionality?

In order to use moveTo, you need to first use ped Exit using the condition "stay where they are". After that the pedestrians are transformed into normal agents that accept all kinds of agent behavior.
Otherwise you need to move pedestrians using the normal pedestrian blocks from the library.
Nevertheless... if you use moveTo, the pedestrians will not behave as pedestrians so they can crush with walls and with other pedestrians...

Just to expand on this correct answer: pedestrians are designed to be used with the ped logic blocks, less so for generic agent capabilities. They are "specialised" agents but loose some capabilities along the way...
